# Expressing number in exponential format

Tags: flex4, numbers, exponent

We are working on a flex project

I need to display a number coming from a calculation in exponential format- essentially, show 80900 as 8.09* 10^4; 4.1e-4 as 4.1*10^-4 etc

Any simple way by which I can take the number and separate the exponent and the significand- without getting into string operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look into `Number.toExponential()` method described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5#toExponential%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

See if [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=1pHCLyoi1sgC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=flex+numberformatter+exponential&source=bl&ots=LhuyFh6UWE&sig=YpojAwDPoNJsumrlzUawfDrg1G8&hl=en&ei=XsqlTePSCISSswa987CUCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=flex%20numberformatter%20exponential&f=false) helps:

> "Let's create a custom formatter to
>   change a regular number format to an
>   exponential notation or a fixed-point
>   notation with two fractional digits"